# WordPress update_option - use in a file where the WP files are not included

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a WP plugin and have an issue.

In the pludin's settings area, there is a form, where the content is sent to a file (save.php) trough AJAX. 
So, the save.php file has no access to WP's update_option function.

How can I use the option functions in the save.php file?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */
    require_once( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/wp-load.php' );
```